# Use unsigned applet

Tags: java, security, applet

I just programmed a simple applet. The problem is that my applet isn't able to communicate with my servlet running on port 8181. Every time the applet tries to establish a connection I get the error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" " Server IP:80" "connect,resolve")
```

I already added my applet to the whitelist of java security control, but this doesn't solve the problem. 
I can't imagine that there is no way to make this work. The applet is just for my own use, so i dont see the need to sign it.

Comment: *"I just programmed a simple applet."*  The term 'simple applet' is an oxymoron.  It does not exist.  *"The applet is just for my own use"*  Then save yourself from a world of pain by making it a `JFrame` based desktop app. - my 'copy/paste comment on applets is.. Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  (But ignore the bit about the teacher, and just read it as general warnings.)

Comment: Indeed it is for an assignment. I will try to change his mind ;) Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't see the need. But your view does not matter in this case. Since Java 7u25 **all applets must be signed**.

See the Oracle page on [Java Applet & Web Start - Code Signing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html) for details.

Comment: ok thank you for your quick response. I already searched how to sign an applet, because I feared I had to sign it. But there is just one more question bothering me. Can I self-sign my applet or is it just able to work, when I use an certificate of an certain CA? I found multiple answers on this question on the web so I'm not quite sure.

Comment: *"Can I self-sign my applet"*  No, not and have it work.  It used to be possible, but is not anymore.